testing for bytemuck casting alignment issues
I have the following struct with conversion logic:
enum TagType {
  DOUBLE,
  BYTE,
}

impl TagType {
  /// byte-size actually
  fn size(&self) -> usize {
    match self {
      TagType::DOUBLE => 8,
      TagType::BYTE => 1,
    }
  }
}
/// Entry with buffered data.
///
/// Should not be used for tags where the data fits in the offset field
/// byte-order of the data should be native-endian in this buffer
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone)]
pub struct BufferedEntry {
    pub tag_type: TagType,
    pub count: u64,
    pub data: Vec<u8>,
}

impl<'a> TryFrom<&'a BufferedEntry> for &'a [f64] {
    type Error = ();

    fn try_from(val: &'a BufferedEntry) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        if val.data.len() != val.tag_type.size() * usize::try_from(val.count)? {
            return Err(());
        }
        match val.tag_type {
            TagType::DOUBLE => Ok(bytemuck::cast_slice(&val.data()[..])),
            _ => Err(()),
        }
    }
}

Now, this will panic if the input vec is not properly aligned to an 8-byte boundary, which I cannot do. Or well, rkyv has AlignedVec which should be exactly what I need. The question, however, is: How can I test for this? e.g. how could I write a test that allocates a non-64-aligned vector?

As far as I know, you can't force the Allocator to reduce alignment. Normal Allocator's typically have a minimum alignment. Instead, with nightly Rust, you can use your own dubious Allocator:
#![feature(allocator_api)]
#![feature(ptr_metadata)]

use std::alloc::{AllocError, Allocator, Layout, System};
use std::ptr::NonNull;

fn main() {
    let unaligned = Vec::<u8, _>::with_capacity_in(1, MinimizeAlignment);

    // Ok.
    assert!(unaligned.as_ptr().addr() % 2 != 0);

    // Panic.
    bytemuck::cast_slice::<u8, f64>(&unaligned);
}

/// Allocations are aligned based on `Layout` (in
/// that accessing them is perfectly sound), but
/// not over-aligned unlike typical allocators
/// which align to several words regardless of
/// `Layout`.
struct MinimizeAlignment;

unsafe impl Allocator for MinimizeAlignment {
    fn allocate(&self, layout: Layout) -> Result<NonNull<[u8]>, AllocError> {
        let new =
            Layout::from_size_align(layout.size() + layout.align(), layout.align() * 2).unwrap();
        let slice = System.allocate(new)?;
        let (ptr, meta) = slice.to_raw_parts();
        let slice = unsafe { NonNull::from_raw_parts(ptr.byte_add(layout.align()), meta - layout.align()) };
        Ok(slice)
    }

    unsafe fn deallocate(&self, ptr: NonNull<u8>, layout: Layout) {
        let new =
            Layout::from_size_align(layout.size() + layout.align(), layout.align() * 2).unwrap();
        System.deallocate(unsafe { ptr.sub(layout.align()) }, new)
    }
}


Apart from that, there's also an error (that results in an unsound call to byte_add): the raw slice pointer returned by allocate still has the adjusted size of new and therefore ends outside the bounds of the allocation; you'll need to create a new slice pointer with the appropriate length, e.g. using std::ptr::slice_from_raw_parts_mut or (on nightly with the ptr_metadata feature) NonNull::from_raw_parts.

@eggyal thanks so much! You're right about the second issue, I forgot to shorten the slice! I don't think the first issue is a separate error. My fixed implementation meets the size (layout.size() + any extra from System + layout.align() - layout.align() >= layout.size()) and align ((layout.align() * 2 * N + layout.align()) % layout.align() == 0) requirements.

[1/2]@eggyal the idea of MinimizeAlignment.allocate is that the pointers are aligned in the soundness-critical "minimum alignment of type X" sense but not over-aligned in the "minimum alignment of allocator Y" sense. E.g. a Vec<u16> with alignment of 2 will have an address with a 0 least-significant-bit but a 1 second-to-least-significant bit. All alignments are powers of two. Doubling the alignment requirement passed to System.allocate results in a soundly-aligned address. Adding the alignment to that address keeps it soundly-aligned.

[2/2] Miri can detect the type of alignment problem you claims exists when the pointer is accessed i.e. vec.push(). Tools -> Miri is silent on this modified code :)

Apologies, for some inexplicable reason I had it in my head that this was issuing pointers with half the requested alignment - but that is of course not the case.
